# ElasticSearch Results with a really low score?

Tags: elasticsearch, ranking

I have a problem regarded to the results of ElasticSearch.

In one document I have 800 pages sized text in one field. The word I want to query for just appears once in this document.

When I search my index ElasticSearch doesn't list it in the result.

Maybe the score is much too low?

I have this problem in more cases than just this one. Is there a possibility to list also documents with a very low result as well?

best regards!

Comment: normally a low frequency should lead to a higher score, some more information would be helpful

Comment: Do you get other results or 0 hits? Maybe the doc isn't in the page you're looking at? Otherwise it just doesn't match.

Comment: I get hits it is not empty. 

I know that word appears in the document. In other documents this world also apperas just one time but the documents have much less pages and so much less words. ElasticSerach find them. 

The document is also indexed, with other queries I can find the document. 

The document is an attachement field, may be this information is important to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the analyzer. Since in Elasticsearch default analyzer less then or equal to 4  char words cannot be searched.

Comment: But the specific word has 14 chars and will be find in other documents. That is what I wondering about

Comment: If your file is big then then  in conf set this parameter index.mapping.attachment.indexed_chars=-1[https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments#indexed-characters]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your "size" parameter is set high enough? By default ES returns only 10 matches, it does match, but it's ranked lower ten that you won't see it.